# При значениях больше 124 переменная становится null

Tags: javascript, php

После нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить", все данные таблицы отправляются в базу данных. Также необходимо отправлять количество строк, в данном случае это 124. Проблема в том что если количество строк превышает 124. Это поле возвращает NULL. Т.е до количества 124 работает всё нормально. При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить строку" добавляется строка в таблицу и в поле меняется значение и становится 125, 126 и т.д., но после значения 124 это поле возвращает NULL и товары не добавляются в базу.

**Форма**

```
<form method='POST' action='pipe_add.php'>
    <table class='products__table'>
        <tbody id='tblist'>
            <tr class='tr_head'>
                <td class="ignore busy">✔</td>
                <td class="hide ignore busy">#</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Диаметр d</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Толщина стенки</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Пм в 1 тн.</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Производитель</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Единица измерения</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Цена безнал.</td>
                <td class="ignore busy">Цена налич.</td>
            </tr>
            <?
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($result_r_p as $row) {
                echo "<tr>
                    <td class='ignore busy'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='" . $row['id'] . "'></td>
                    <td class='hide ignore busy'><input readonly class='hide form-control' id='id' name='id[" . $i . "] ' value='" . $row['id'] . "' size='3' maxlength='4'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control size_a' name='size_a[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['size_a'] . "' size='4' maxlength='4'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control size_c' name='size_c[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['size_c'] . "' size='4' maxlength='4'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control meters_tonne' name='meters_tonne[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['meters_tonne'] . "' size='3' maxlength='4'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control manufacturer' name='manufacturer[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['manufacturer'] . "'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control unit' name='unit[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['unit'] . "' size='3' maxlength='4'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control price_transfer' name='price_transfer[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['price_transfer'] . "' size='7' maxlength='15'></td>
                    <td><input class='form-control price_cash' name='price_cash[" . $i . "]' value='" . $row['price_cash'] . "' size='7' maxlength='15'></td>
                    </tr>";
                $i++;
            }
            ?>

            <tr class='send_button_tr'>
            <td class="ignore busy"><input class="btn btn-success" type='submit' name='add_btn' id='add_btn' value='Сохранить'></td>
            <td class="ignore busy"><input class="btn btn-danger" type='submit' name='delete_btn' id='delete_btn' value='Удалить'></td>
            <td class="ignore busy"><input readonly class='form-control' id='hide_count_field' name='hide_field' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**PHP-код**

```
<?php

include '../config.php';

$link     = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die ('No connect');
$db       = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);
$result   = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM pipe_prod");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (isset($_POST['add_btn'])) {

    // Подключение к базе данных
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

    $arrayId        = $_POST['id'];
    $arraySizeA      = $_POST['size_a'];
    $arraySizeC      = $_POST['size_c'];
    $arrayMetr      = $_POST['meters_tonne'];
    $arrayManufact  = $_POST['manufacturer'];
    $arrayUnit      = $_POST['unit'];
    $arrayTransfer  = $_POST['price_transfer'];
    $countOfStrokes = $_POST['hide_field'];
    $arrayCash      = $_POST['price_cash'];

    for($t = 0; $t < $countOfStrokes; $t++) {

        $id             = $t + 1;
        $parseId        = $arrayId[$t];
        $sizeA          = $arraySizeA[$t];
        $sizeC          = $arraySizeC[$t];
        $meters_tonne   = $arrayMetr[$t];
        $manufacturer   = $arrayManufact[$t];
        $unit           = $arrayUnit[$t];
        $price_transfer = $arrayTransfer[$t];
        $price_cash     = $arrayCash[$t];

        // ИЗМЕНЯЕТ СУЩЕСТВУЮЩИЕ ПРОДУКТЫ
        if ($id <= $num_rows) {
            $result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `pipe_prod` SET size_a = '$sizeA', size_c = '$sizeC', meters_tonne = '$meters_tonne', manufacturer = '$manufacturer', unit = '$unit', price_transfer = '$price_transfer', price_cash = '$price_cash' WHERE id = '$parseId'");
            echo "<br>edited";
            //echo "<br>$id";

            //СОЗДАЁТ НОВЫЕ ПРОДУКТЫ
        } else {
            $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `pipe_prod` (id, size_a, size_c, meters_tonne, manufacturer, unit, price_transfer, price_cash) VALUES (NULL, '$sizeA','$sizeC','$meters_tonne','$manufacturer','$unit','$price_transfer','$price_cash')");
            echo "<br>added";
            //echo "<br>$id";
        }
    }

    if ($result == true){
        echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
    } else {
        echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
    }
}
?>
```

**JS-код**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    callCellSelect();

    el = document.querySelector('div.wrapper');
    matches = el.querySelectorAll("tr").length - 2;
    $('div.wrapper #hide_count_field').attr('value','' + matches + '');

    table = $('div.wrapper').children().children();

    $('.add_stroke').off().click(function() {

        //КОЛИЧЕСТВО tr ТАБЛИЦЫ
        newTr = table.children().children().length;

        //ИЩЕМ МАКСИМАЛЬНОЕ id
        tdId = table.children().children().not('tr:first-child').not('tr:last-child').children('td:nth-child(2)');
        arrTdId = [];
        $(tdId).each(function(i,e) {
            hz = $(e).children().attr('value');
            arrTdId[i] = parseInt(hz);
        });
        maxId = Math.max.apply(null, arrTdId);
        idValue = maxId + 1;

        //СЧИТАЕМ КОЛИЧЕСТВО ПРОДУКТОВ(СТРОК) ТАБЛИЦЫ
        trCount = newTr - 2;
        el = document.querySelector('div.wrapper');
        matches = el.querySelectorAll("tr").length - 1;
        $('div.wrapper #hide_count_field').attr('value','' + matches + '');

        //ДОБАВЛЯЕМ НОВЫЙ ПРОДУКТ(СТРОКУ В КОНЕЦ ТАБЛИЦЫ)
        newStroke = "<tr><td class='ignore busy'><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='test'></td><td class='hide ignore busy'><input readonly class='hide form-control id' name='id[" + trCount + "]' value='' size='3' maxlength='4'></td><td><input class='form-control size_a' name='size_a[" + trCount + "]' value='' size='4' maxlength='4'></td><td class='cell-c'><input class='form-control size_c' name='size_c[" + trCount + "]' value='' size='4' maxlength='4'></td><td class='cell-c'><input class='form-control meters_tonne' name='meters_tonne[" + trCount + "]' value='' size='3' maxlength='4'></td><td><input class='form-control manufacturer' name='manufacturer[" + trCount + "]' value=''></td><td class='cell-c'><input size='3' class='form-control unit' name='unit[" + trCount + "]' value='пм.' size='3' maxlength='4'></td><td class='cell-c'><input size='7' class='form-control price_transfer' name='price_transfer[" + trCount + "]' value='' size='7' maxlength='15'></td><td class='cell-c'><input  size='7' class='form-control price_cash' name='price_cash[" + trCount + "]' value='' size='7' maxlength='15'></td></tr>";

        $(newStroke).insertBefore('div.wrapper .send_button_tr');

        callCellSelect();
    });


});
```

Comment: Если у вас проблема с отправкой конкретного значения на сервер, то не надо приводить в вопросе картинки и РНР код. Надо приводить **клиентский код.** То есть - javascript

Comment: Если количество строк нужно только для цикла, то отправлять его в РНР не нужно, перебрать массив можно и без него

Comment: Картинка была приведена для полного понимания вида проекта. А отправка значений происходит не через js, а через PHP код который вы видимо удалили.

Comment: Советуете перебрать массив в JS?

Comment: @ШерзодНоров но в PHP значения сами по себе из ниоткуда не возьмутся, их всё же отправляет клиент, значит нужен и код клиента тоже (если вы не продемонстрируете, что в PHP все значения поступают как нужно)

Comment: У вас проблема с отправкой не из РНР в mysql, а **из javascript в РНР**

Comment: Всё работало прекрасно до количества строк 124. Например изначально в таблице 50 строк. И я спокойно добавлял новые строки и сохранял, они отправлялись в базу данных. Но когда дошёл до 124 строки перестали отправляться. Использую var_dump. Вычислил что после количества строк 124 поле input с id = hide_count_field возвращает NULL.

Comment: javascript ничего не отправляет. Он используется только для добавления количества строк в поле input с id='hide_count_field'

Comment: ну так вот и разбирайтесь с **javascript** кодом, который используется только для добавления количества строк в поле input с id='hide_count_field'. при чем здесь РНР?

Comment: И снова повторю - к РНР, и уж тем более к mysql проблема с переменной в яваскрипте не имеет никакого отношения

Comment: с js кодом всё в порядке. Он как и должен заносит количество строк в поле input. 124, 125, 126 и т.д. Проблема в $countOfStrokes = $_POST['hide_field']; это возвращает NULL после количества строк 124. Если в поле стоит значение 125 оно возвращает NULL. Привёл также весь код js

Comment: hide_count_field это id поля. Имя поля hide_count. И обращение идёт по имени. Следовательно здесь всё правильно

Comment: Если  $_POST['hide_field'] равно null, это значит что значение hide_field **Не было передано с клиента.**

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос в том, почему до того как количество строк равно 124 поле передаёт значение. А после количества строк 124 поле передаёт NULL

Comment: `post_max_size`?

Comment: @u_mulder bingo. только max_input_vars. Шерзод Норов приношу свои извинения, я был неправ.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Предполагал что стоит лимит, но не смог найти информацию по этому.